# Training classifier in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pycharm

I wrote a classifier in Python (PyCharm). It does not display the training stages of the model. how can this be fixed in my code? I want to see the training stages of my classifier. Everything is displayed in case working in Jupiter notebook (you can see it in the picture).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['SEPAL_LENGTH', 'SEPAL_WIDTH', 'PETAL_LENGTH', 'PETAL_WIDTH', 'SPECIES']

data = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- databases/iris/iris.data', names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['SPECIES'] = encoder.fit_transform(data['SPECIES'])
print(data.head())
X = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.columns.drop('SPECIES'))

y = data.pop('SPECIES')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

def input_fn(features, labels, training = True, batch_size = 256):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    dataset = dataset.batch(10)
    if training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()

    return dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()

my_feature_columns = [] # to record the features

for key in X_train.keys():
    my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=my_feature_columns, hidden_units=. [30,10], n_classes=3)


 classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(X_train, y_train, training=True), steps=5)

 classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(X_test, y_test, training=False))
 print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**train_result))
```

Comment: Hi Isaeva, You can use Tensorflow’s TensorBoard for Visualization to display the training stages for your classifier in PyCharm.
TensorBoard provides interactive Visualization and monitoring of various aspects of your models.
You need to installed Tensorflow in your environment. You can install it using pip by this command if you have'nt already.
`pip install tensorflow` and you can add the following imports to your code.
`import os
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`.